# Как сделать такое же перемещение?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css-animation

http://lp1.wunder.kz/features/Как сделать такое же перемещение динозавра, появление новых объектов таких как очки и плащ?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почитать учебники по яваскрипту и html/css. Или расковырять сайт-образец в веб-инспекторе и спереть готовое решение.

Comment: Сайт на Wordpress сделан((